# data presentation based on object type in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an API that gives back a single JSON Object if there is only one element in the response and gives back an array of objects if there is more than one element in the response.

I could use the javascript controller to simply make it always an array even with just one object in it, and loop through the array with ng-repeat, but the problem is that I have the same issue in some properties of the JSON object too.

I don´t want to change the JSON structure of the data and I might need them to update the record via the API, so I was looking for a way to handle this in Angular 1.x.

Is there a simple way in angular to display the data regardless if it is only one object or an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do that. It is simpler if you transform the one object into array in your controller:

```
getSomething(...).then(res =>  res.length ? res : [res])
                 .then(resArr => $scope.somethings = resArr);
```

Comment: He's saying that often there are nested properties on ```res``` with the same situation (could be an array or an object). This doesn't account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to modify the response you're getting back. Otherwise you will have to do a lot of awkward, case-by-case checks scattered all over your view logic.

You will probably need a service layer between your controllers and the API which "translates" the JSON data. So, when requesting data, it will loop through the response recursively and wrap all the lone objects in arrays.

Then, when posting data to the API, it will loop back through again and remove the array wrappers from lone objects.